# Plotting grouped continuous variable vs. binary variable

Tags: r, dataframe, figure

I have a continuous response variable, and a binary predictor variable. However, that binary predictor also comes in two flavors (two different years). I'd like to create a box plot with the two years separate but in the same x-variable column.

Here's a hypothetical dataframe setup like mine

```
    Wingspan     Infected     Year
    15.3         1            2015
    14.9         1            2015
    15.9         0            2016  
    15.0         1            2016
    13.8         0            2015
    16.1         0            2016
    14.2         1            2015
    15.9         1            2015 
    13.7         0            2016
    16.4         0            2016
    13.9         0            2016
    14.0         1            2015
```

It's easy for me to get an output by doing

```
    Model <- Wingspan ~ Infected
    plot(Model)
```

However, I want the Infected columns to have 2 boxes per column, one for 2015 and one for 2016. I've tried all sorts of functions to split the data like split() and various bind functions but I can't seem to partition this data in any way and get an output. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Pretty sure this is a dplyr "long to wide" problem but need to verify.

Comment: `boxplot(Wingspan ~ Infected + Year, data=dat)` ?

Comment: @mysteRious that one is not a 'long to wide' problem, one can perfectly create graphs with this data. What is a bit unclear,  though, which type of graph the OP wants to create. The example code produces a dot plot, but the OP speaks of boxes.

Comment: @D.Money see also my suggestion for a different title.

Comment: @mysteRious Do you mean I should post my actual data? Sorry, I'm new to posting and it's not as easy as it looks.

Comment: @Tjebo I was very imprecise. I guess I figured that as long as I could figure out how to split the data by year then I could turn the dot plot into a boxplot. And thanks for the new title!

Comment: That is not complicated then. either use @thelatemails code, or, for somewhat "nicer" graphs, I would suggest [tag:ggplot], a fantastic package for graphs. Basically a must have. I add some code to my answer to give a suggestion. And no. You do not need to change your data. It's absolute fine and, actually, already "long".

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you would like:

```
require(read.so) #Awesome package by @Alistaire47
dat <- read.so()
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(as.character(Infected), Wingspan, color = as.character(Year))) + 
geom_point()
#I have used as.character in order to prevent R reading the numbers as , 
#... well... , numbers
```

[image]

**edit 1** 
For boxplots, simply change `geom_point()` to `geom_boxplot()`... that's all :)

**edit 2**
for different colors in base R, add the following to @thelatemail's code:

```
boxplot(Wingspan ~ Infected + Year, data=dat, boxfill = dat$Year)
#again, try ggplot. Very rewarding, in terms of getting nice graphs.
```

[image]

Comment: This is basically what I'm looking for, yes! I know there's a saying about beggars and choosers, but...is there a way to do this in base R? I only ask because I'm a bit iffy on ggplot syntax and I told myself I should be able to use basic commands to play with these data. But I'm very thankful for your answer, and I'll be using it if I can't find an alternative.

Comment: I am not very good in base R plotting. However, I would definitely encourage you to have a go at ggplot. The syntax is really not complicated and it is soooo versatile.